# Weird constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor, enums

I have to write a class called Tile.

I have a given main.cpp which I cannot change. My question is on the constructor call in the given main function.

The given main at the bottom calls the constructor with `Tile(Tile::TYPE_CROSS, COLOR_RED);` and it's giving me an error: "`Class Tile does not have a member TYPE_CROSS`." Works on `COLOR_RED` though.

My question is, why is this called like this, with `Tile(Tile::TYPE_CROSS,...)`
and not like I would do, for example `Tile(TYPE_CROSS, COLOR_RED);`.

With this it doesn't give me errors, but unfortunately I can't change the main.
Also, I have to use enums for the stuff in the class.

Tile.h (by me):

```
#ifndef TILE_H
#define TILE_H

enum Type
{
  TYPE_CROSS = 1,
  TYPE_CURVE_1 = 2,
  TYPE_CURVE_2 = 3
};

enum Color
{
  COLOR_RED = 1,
  COLOR_WHITE = 2
};

class Tile
{
private:
  Type side_;
  Color top_color_;
public:
  Tile(); // Default constructor
  Tile(Type side, Color orientation); // Constructor
  ~Tile();
};

#endif
```

Tile.cpp (by me):

```
#include "Tile.h"

// Constructor
Tile::Tile(Type side, Color orientation)
{
  side_ = side;
  top_color_ = orientation;
}
```

Given main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Tile(Tile::TYPE_CROSS, COLOR_RED); // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE

  //Tile(TYPE_CROSS, COLOR_RED);
  //Tile t1(TYPE_CROSS, COLOR_RED);
  return 0;
}
```

Ignore the missing destructor, I will add it later.

Comment: The problem is that the class `Tile` does not have a member called `TYPE_CROSS`.

Comment: That should not compile, as the `Type` enumeration is not part of the `Tile` class.

Comment: `TYPE_CROSS` is in the global namespace, not inside `Tile`, so `Tile::TYPE_CROSS` is simply wrong. If you can't change `main`, then you'll have to move `Type` inside `Tile`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I moved the Type enum inside Tile under public and now it seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
enum Color
{
  COLOR_RED = 1,
  COLOR_WHITE = 2
};

class Tile
{
private:

  Color top_color_;
public:

enum Type
{
  TYPE_CROSS = 1,
  TYPE_CURVE_1 = 2,
  TYPE_CURVE_2 = 3
};
Type side_;
  Tile(); // Default constructor
  Tile(Type side, Color orientation); // Constructor
  //~Tile();
};
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but it makes side_ public.

What I did was, make a public block for the enum, then a private block for top_color_ and side_ and then again a public block for the methods.

Thanks nevertheless.